# Initializing pointer from argv to compare addresses

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, argv

I am just beginning with C, read a lot about pointers and arrays, but can't seem to understand why my piece of code won't run properly.

I am trying to condition a while loop using the address of argv first element without success. I am convinced I am using argv the wrong way.

Here is the code:

```
int main(int k, const char* argv[]) 
{   const char** first = NULL ;
    first = &argv[0] ;
    argv += k ;
    while (argv > first) puts(*argv), argv-- ; 
    return 0 ; }
```

Returns a segmentation fault.

This is what I am doing in my head:

Create a pointer first, assign it to NULL (using two * because of argv type)

Assign this pointer to the address of argv first element, argv[0] to make it obvious.

Move argv by argc (k)

The while loop is comparing argv address to first address, and print *argv as long as argv isn't reaching this first address, then decrement argv.

The above code should indeed return all the elements on a command line, starting from the last and ignoring the first (program's name).

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `argv[k]` (before the modifications to `argv` in your code) is defined to be a null pointer. By doing `argv += k` you make `argv` point to that null pointer, which you then pass to `puts`, leading to *undefined behavior* when `puts` tries to use that null pointer.

One possible way to solve it is to do e.g. `argv += (k - 1)` instead.

Comment: I used `printf` instead of `puts` and got the first string to be printed `(null)`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than changing the value of `argv` itself, why not simply manipulate the pointer you have pointing to `argv` (or to the element within it). When you increment or decrement `argv` itself, you lose the reference to the original pointer. Yes, you can store a copy..., but you went to the trouble of declaring a pointer to `argv`, just apply your `k` (or `argc`) offset to the pointer, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char **p = argv;                 /* pointer to argv */
    p += argc - 1;                   /* advance to last */

    printf ("\nin order:");          /* output original order */
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        printf (" %s", argv[i]);

    printf ("\nreverse :");          /* decrement p outputting in reverse */
    while (p > argv)
        printf (" %s", *p--);

    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/argvptr my dog has fleas

in order: my dog has fleas
reverse : fleas has dog my
```

Comment: Note HS: I still don't understand why people continue to declare variable in the beginning of their function and not where they need it.

Comment: Generally because they have `cl.exe` on Win7 and need a C89 compatible declaration for it to be portable between compilers? `:)`

Comment: Their life must be terrible ! But I think unless OP tag a specific compiler or C version, answers should reflect the best available feature. OP is learning programming. (MSVC still don't support this basic feature ?!)

Comment: Oh, it's worse than that.... Just try and use any meaningful function like `clock_gettime` or anything needing `unistd.h` or `sys/select.h`. Cobbling `QueryPerformanceCounter` from `Windows.h` into a C program just to get a decent timer to work really shows the age of that compiler. But, some still cling to the old windoze `:)` I have it virtualized on a server with virtualbox and run it headless in a window via rdesktop just for testing purposes...

Answer (score 0):

Size of argv in your case is 1 which means only argv[0] is valid
while producing argv+=k you exceed array boundaries

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm missing something here. If you just want to print the arguments in reverse order, why not simply use something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    for (i = argc - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        puts(argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suppose that the OP want to train pointer skill. Note that your answer doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Thank you August, but the reason I use that specific solution is because the exercise is formulated such way, trying to train pointer skills as Stargateur noted. Thank you for the alternative solution though.